# Regex for abbreviation doesn't work properly in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I want to replace the abbreviation "etc." in a csv file with its full form "et cetera".
The csv test file can be seen below:

```
# Audio_Filename|Segment_Text
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, etc.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes etc.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, etc..
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes etc..
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, etc. but I'm broke.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes etc. but I'm broke.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes etc., but I'm broke.
```

With my current code, only the abbreviations in the middle of the sentence get replaced but not at the end of a sentence. I want to match all of the "etc." in this file.

With a regex tester, all "etc." are correctly matched, but my code results in omitting the punktuation mark at the end of the sentences or after the abbreviation itself (probably due to the grouping in my code). I have tried many other options but nothing works as desired.
How can I get this right?

Any hint is much appreciated, thanks!

**My code:**

```
import re 
import pandas as pd

# Read file into dataframe.
with open('/home/user/data/test.csv') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['Audio_Filename', 'Segment_Text'], sep='|')
    # Replace abbreviation.
    df['Segment_Text'].replace(to_replace=r'(\W)?( )?etc\.( )?(\W|\d)', value=r'\1 et cetera \4', regex=True, inplace=True)
    # Write dataframe to new file.
    df.to_csv('/home/user/data/test_replaced.csv',
              header=False, index=False, sep='|')
```

**Result:**

```
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, etc.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes etc.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera but I'm broke.  # works
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera but I'm broke.  # works
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera, but I'm broke.  # works
```

**Desired result:**

```
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera..
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera..
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera but I'm broke.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera but I'm broke.
fa73f311.wav|I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera, but I'm broke.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a single multiline string in the online regex tester, and the `etc.` on the first line is actually not at the end of string, it is followed with a line break, `\n`, then `fa73f311.wav`, and so on, so the `( )?(\W|\d)` part can match. When you serve separate strings to the regex, the `( )?(\W|\d)` can't match the obligatory non-word or a digit char.

You can use word and non-word boundary here:

```
df['Segment_Text'].replace(to_replace=r'\betc\.\B', value=r'et cetera', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kf6R6H/1).

Alternatively, to keep the same logic with your `(\W|d)` (to require a match if the `etc.` is followed with a non-word char or a digit), you can use

```py
\betc\.(?![^\W\d])
```

where `(?![^\W\d])` requires a location followed with a non-word char or a digit or end of string.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kf6R6H/2).

Answer (score 0):

The notion is to use `str.replace` rather than `replace`.

```
df['Segment_Text'] = df['Segment_Text'].str.replace(r'(\s)?etc\.', r'\1et cetera')
df['Segment_Text']

0            I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera
1             I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera
2           I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera.
3            I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera.
4    I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera but ...
5    I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera but I...
6    I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera, but ...
```

If you are sure you are dealing with correct english sentences like the ones provided, then `etc\.` alone should be enough eg:

```
df['Segment_Text'].str.replace('etc\.','et cetera')

0            I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera
1             I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera
2           I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera.
3            I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera.
4    I'd like to buy shoes, clothes, et cetera but ...
5    I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera but I...
6    I'd like to buy shoes, clothes et cetera, but ...
```